# Laminate floor boards cut too short

Tags: flooring, laminate

my contractor cut the laminate boards too short leaving about 1/8" gap in some places and installed them. Any way to make them looking good?

Comment: Adding a few pictures would sure help to come up with a good solution.

Comment: Did you pay him in full? If not, it needs to be on him to make the job look good. If you did pay in full, that tells him the job is acceptable. A company that wants to keep a good reputation will fix it even if the full payment has been made...typically....

Comment: use thicker base molding or quarter round to cover the gap. you could also standoff the trim from the wall by using a spacer between the trim and the wall, nailing through it; something like bit of cardboard, washer, giftcard, etc. You then caulk the narrow gap before you paint and it will look like nothing different.

Comment: With laminate there is supposed to be a gap around the edges to allow for movement.  Is that what we are talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

When you say two short are the mop boards or trim in place? If it can be seen with the trim make the contractor repair , longer flooring or thicker trim. The reason you hire a pro is for it to look good not diy. If the contractor gives you a hard time forward copies of the contract and pictures of the gaps to the BBB and contractors board.